# load balancing webserver / IIS / MSSQL - many clients

Tags: sql-server, iis, load-balancing

Have to say im not an administrator of any sorts and never needed to distribute load on a server before, but now im in a situation where i can see that i might have a problem.

This is the scenario and my problem :

I have a IIS running on a server with a MSSQL, a client can send off a request that will retrieve a datapackage with a request (1 request) to the MSSQL database, that data is then sent back to the client.

This package of data can be of different lenght, but generally <10 MB.

This is all working fine, but im now facing a what-if if i have 10.000 clients pounding on the server simulataniously, i can see my bandwith getting smashed probably and also imagine that both IIS and MSSQL will be dying of exhaustion.

So my question is, i guess the bandwith issue is only about hosting ? but how can i distribute this so IIS and MSSQL will be able to perform without exhausting them ?

Really appriciate an explanation of how this can be achieved, its probably standard knowledge but for me its abit of a mystery, but know it can be done when i look at dropbox and whatelse just a big question how i can do it.

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You will need to consider some form of Load Balancing. Since you are using IIS, I'm assuming that you are hosting on Windows Server, which provides a software based Network Load Balancer. See [Network Load Balancing Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742455.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the performance bottleneck then plan to reduce them. A sledgehammer approach here might not be the best idea.

Setup performance counters and record a day or two's worth of data. See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966540.aspx) link on how to do SQL server performance troubleshooting.

The bandwidth might just be one of the problems. By setting up performance counters and doing a analysis of what is actually happening you will be able to plan a better solution with the right data.